# How to generate a number in C# which re start from 1 on every new date

Tags: c#

How to generate a number in C# which start from 1 on every new date.For Example if number ended on 90 on 15 june it should be start from 1 again on 16 june. Working on a clinic Software and their requirement is that their Patient token number should start from 1 on every new day.Please Help me.
It gets a number for me but i want to start it from 1 on new day

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(
  "select TOP 1 token_m from token ORDER BY token_m DESC;", 
   con);

con.Open();

SqlDataReader dr1 = cm.ExecuteReader();

while (dr1.Read())
{
    token_m = (Int32.Parse(dr1[0].ToString().Trim()) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code..

Comment: You need to know what was the last day your program has been used and restart the sequence when the day changes. Where do you store the list of patients? And do you store also the date in which they are listed in your system for their appointments? To answer correctly you need to give more details on this system

Comment: i store their date and token number in database

Comment: You should be aware that code that works like this is not 100% reliable in multi-user scenarios.

Comment: Does the Token table you are selecting from have a date/time stamp inside of it? this way you only need to select tokens that have the current date.. if none are found create token 1 else increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand what you want, but if you need to replace values from DB with dynamically generated ids, you should store the last number and the last assignment date, then on each assignment update date and check if it is new day.

```
private static DateTime _lastAssigned = DateTime.Min;
private static int _lastId = 1;

...

while (dr1.Read())
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    if (now.Day > _lastAssigned.Day ||
        now.Month > _lastAssigned.Month ||
        now.Year > _lastAssigned.Year)
        _lastId = 1;
    txt_id.Text = _lastId.ToString();
    _lastId++;
    _lastAssignment = now;
}
```

Comment: wow..it somehow doing trick for me. Thanks a lot.need some more work to do on it but providing me a base

Answer (score 0):

I have written some sample code. You may tweak it as per your needs:

```
class Program
{
    static System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
    static int tokenCounter;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;
        t.AutoReset = true;            
        var date = (DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).Date - DateTime.Now);
        t.Interval = date.TotalMilliseconds;
        t.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            tokenCounter++;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            Console.WriteLine(tokenCounter);
        }
    }

    static void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        tokenCounter = 0;
    }
}
```